# Does a homeomorphism between two compact metric spaces preserve open balls?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

More specifically, if $X$ and $Y$ are compact metric spaces, and there is a $\phi: X \to Y$ a homeomorphism, then is it true that $\phi^{-1}(B(\phi(x),r))= B(x,r)$ ? If so, how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not true.  Consider $f(x)=x^2$ on the closed interval $[0,1]$

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I did not think it was true but I asked as I needed this or something similar to finish a proof of a claim that I was working on. I will ask the claim now in a separate post.

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily. For that, you would need an isometry.

Consider $X=Y=[0,1]$ with the usual metric. Then for any integer $n>1,$ the map $x\mapsto x^n$ is a homeomorphism, but doesn't preserve open balls.

Comment: Thanks, my question was really intended to get me through a proof, I was wondering if you guys could help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387303/if-x-and-y-are-topologically-conjugate-then-a-homeomorphism-t-on-x-is-minimal-i

Answer (score 4):

No: Consider $(x,y,z) \mapsto (3x,y,z).$ That is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R^3$ to itself, and it changes spheres to ellipsoids.

Alright so one wants an example in which the space is compact.

Let the space be $\{z \in \mathbb C : |z| = 1\}.$

Let distances be arc lengths along this circle.

Let $f(z) = \dfrac{2z+1}{z+2}.$

I'll leave it as an exercise to see that this is a homeomorphism of this space.

It maps $1$ to $1,$ $-1$ to $-1,$ and $i$ to $(4+3i)/5.$ The distance between $1$ and $i$ is more than the distance between $f(1)$ and $f(i).$

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^3$ with standard metric is not compact though.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be the set of vertices of an isosceles right triangle, and let $Y$ be the set of vertices of an equilateral triangle. Then $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic compact metric spaces, but $X$ has $6$ open balls, while $Y$ has only $4.$

Comment: Agreed. Did I correctly infer your meaning for "usual metric" from context?

Answer (score 1):

The metrics $d_1((x,y),(x',y'))=((x-x')^2+(y-y')^2)^{1/2}$ and $d_2((x,y),(x',y'))=\max (|x-x'|,|y-y'|)$ generate the same topology on $\mathbb R^2.$

So $id_{\mathbb R^2}$ is a homeomorphism from $(\mathbb R^2,d_1) $ to $\mathbb R^2,d_2).$ But $d_1$-balls are round and $d_2$-balls are square.