# If T and S are topologically conjugate homeomorphisms, T on X is minimal iff S on Y is minimal. (Definitions inside)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact metric spaces, $T:X \to X$ and $S: Y \to Y$ homeomorphisms. We say $T$ and $S$ are topologically conjugate if there exists a homeomorphism $\phi: X \to Y$ such that $S(\phi(x))= \phi(T(x))$ for all $x \in X$.

We say a homeomorphism $T$ is minimal if for every $x \in X$, the set $\{T^k x: x\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $X$.

The claim is that T is minimal iff S is minimal.

I have tried to show this but to no avail, as I get stuck trying to compare a ball around x with a ball around $\phi(x)$ which unless its an isometry I can not do anything interesting with to get my result. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your terminology is inaccurate, it should be: "We say $T$ and $S$ [not $X$ and $Y$] are topologically conjugate if there exists $\phi : X \to Y$..."

Comment: Also, please use MathJax for the mathematical formulas https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks Lee Mosher I have edited the title. I will also check MathJax for future use.

Comment: You don't need to use that $\phi$ is an isometry, you only need the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of continuity.

Comment: @LeeMosher: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2387276/28900) is why the OP needs an isometry, based on the approach.

Comment: This claim has a very nice informal explanation: note that $\phi : X \to Y$ acts like a mirror. Every place in $X$ has a faithful reflection on the side of $Y$. Also, every action of $T$ on $X$ faithfully corresponds to an action of $S$ on $Y$, because $S \circ \phi = \phi \circ T$. So really $T$ and $S$ must share every topological property, in particular density of the set $\{ T^k x : k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ for each $x \in X$. From this point of view $(X, T)$ and $(Y, S)$ are absolutely identical.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to assume that $T$ is minimal and prove that $S$ is minimal, since the converse follows by the same argument, swapping $(T,S,\phi) \to (S, T, \phi^{-1})$. In metric spaces, we can use sequences.

Take $y \in Y$. We want to prove that $\{ S^ky \mid y \in Y \}$ is dense in $Y$. Let $y_0 \in Y$. Then $\phi^{-1}(y_0) \in X$, and since $T$ is minimal, there is a sequence $(k_n)_{n \geq 0}$ such that $T^{k_n}(\phi^{-1}(y)) \to \phi^{-1}(y_0)$. By continuity of $\phi$, and noting that $\phi \circ T \circ \phi^{-1} = S$ implies $\phi \circ T^{k_n} \circ \phi^{-1} = S^{k_n}$, we obtain $S^{k_n}(y) \to y_0$. Done.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to prove that if $T$ is minimal, then $S$ is minimal. Suppose $\{T^k(x) \mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a dense subset of $X$ for each $x\in X$. Fix $y\in Y$. To show that $\{S^k(y) \mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $Y$, we let $U$ be a nonempty subset of $Y$. Then $\phi^{-1}(U)$ is a nonempty open subset of $X$, so by the density of $\{T^k(\phi^{-1}(y)) \mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, there exists $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $T^k(\phi^{-1}(y))\in\phi^{-1}(U)$. Therefore $$S^k(y)=S^k(\phi(\phi^{-1}(y)))=\phi(T^k(\phi^{-1}(y)))\in U,$$
as desired.

This shows that not only do we not need $\phi$ to be an isometry, but we don't even require $X$ and $Y$ to be compact or metrizable.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure, proving it for any open set is enough since we simply need to show we can approximate any point by an iterate of some other point, which is the same as showing any open ball around that iterated point will contain the other point?

Comment: That's essentially the idea. In other words, a point $x$ is in the closure of $A$ iff every open set containing $x$ intersects $A$. This gives the characterization that a set $D$ is dense in $X$ iff every nonempty open set in $X$ intersects $D$.

Comment: (+1) for pointing out that compactness and metrizability are irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

The fact you need, which is true for homeomorphisms even when they are not isometries, is this:

- for any homeomorphism $\phi : X \to Y$, a subset $A \subset X$ is dense if and only if the image subset $\phi(A) \subset Y$ is dense.

As the other answers show, if $y = \phi(x)$ you can apply this fact using $A = \{T^k(x) \,|\, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and 
$$\phi(A) = \{\phi(T^k(x)) \,|\, k \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{S^k(\phi(x)) \, | \, k \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{T^k(y) \,|\, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}
$$

You don't need that the homeomorphism is an isometry to prove this fact. You can use the open sets definition of continuity, as the other answers show.

Or, you can use the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition, in the following manner.

Suppose we know that $A \subset X$ is dense. Let's prove that $\phi(A) \subset Y$ is dense. Consider $y \in Y$ and $\epsilon>0$ and the open ball $B(y,\epsilon) \subset Y$. We must find a point of $\phi(A)$ contained in the ball $B(y,\epsilon)$. Let $x = \phi^{-1}(y)$. By continuity of $\phi$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\phi(B(x,\delta)) \subset B(y,\epsilon)$. Since $A \subset X$ is dense, there exists $a \in A$ such that $a \in B(x,\delta)$. It follows that $\phi(a) \in \phi(B(x,\delta)) \subset B(y,\epsilon)$, and clearly $\phi(a) \in \phi(A)$.

Comment: I think you meant $\{S^k(\phi(x))\mid k\in\Bbb Z\}$, etc, when computing $\phi(A)$ in the first part of the answer, no?

Comment: Thanks for the correction @IvoTerek